# Can Android detect of bad sectors on external SD Cards when reformating?

Tags: external-sd, 4.2-jelly-bean, formatting, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, reformat

Title:   Can Android perform surface analysis (Detection of bad sectors) on external SD Cards?

**Reasons for asking:**
 1. At one point, I found tons of old pictures and videos in the 'LostDir' folder.
 2. My tablet and Windows 8 computer ocatilny fail to recognize the card for extended amounts of time.  Often, however, and letting it sit for 1-4 months or less and plugging it in and then taking it out several time repeatedly it will start to work.
 3. A couple of times, my tablet claimed the card was corrupted.
 4. A friend's windows 7 computer was able to access shortly after both my Windows 8 computer and tablet couldn't read it.

**Question**
I would like to know if Android can do any of the following:

- When reformatting an SD Card, can it detect bad sectors?
- If it finds a bad sector, can it map around it, so that it does not affect the card.  What if I reformatted it with separate software or a different OS?
  Also, are there any other ways to ensure the integrity of my Sd card?

**System Information**

OS:   Android 4.2.2

Model:  Samsung Galaxy tab 2  (Wifi)  GtP3113

Age:   About 6 years

SD Card age:  Between 4 and about 6 years.